# Flutter - how to read/write Files on Android 13

Tags: android, flutter, file-permissions

How can I read zip (or other format) file, received from messengers to Downloads folder in Android 13 ?
Following permissions are deprecated:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

New permissions are suitable only for media files:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
```

Read/write file operations fully working with :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
```

but in this case PlayStore rejects the app because of new safety policy rules.

I have a workaround idea to send zip file in video/audio format, but file received from messengers drops into Downloads folder (which require permission), so user must manually move the file from Downloads to Videos, before use file in my app... Any ideas?

Comment: You let the user select the wanted file with ACTION_OPEN_DOCEMENT. No permission needed.

Comment: But if a messenger shares a file you could make your app a share receiver.

Comment: Do you have a clue how to implement this in flutter? To pick file I use file_picker library which returns an error "access denied" in Android 13.